# Update DynamoDB table without Key parameter

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I want update Query in dynamoDB without using key parameter.If i don't use key parameter it shows error i.e. key is missing. With key parameter, query wants primary key value of table that i wan't use. I want Upadte query without using primary key.
Now i am filtering the data and then apply loop to update Data in table.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

DDB requires the partition key to update a record.

SQL style "searched" updates are not possible.